# 3x2 layout handout/annotations from pdf

Tags: beamer, layout, annotations

I have a `slides.pdf` file (no source for it), which I would like to annotate on my own. I would like a 3x2 layout with the slides on the left and latex-notes on the right.

Is there any package or easy to use template for this purpose?

For context: these are (kind of bad) course slides, and I would like to be able to annotate them with LaTeX, such that I cut down on paper waste.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You could use these 3 steps:

- include the external pdf via the `pdfpages` package
- add lines notes with the `\setbeamertemplate{note page}[lined]` macro
- arrange the slides and notes on a 4 on 1 layout using `pgfpages`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[lined]
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}
    
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  pagecommand={
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{%
      \note{{}}
    }
  }
]{test}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]